# Sorting Characters Of A C++ String

Tags: c++, string, sorting

If i have a string is there a built in function to sort the characters or would I have to write my own?

for example:

```
string word = "dabc";
```

I would want to change it so that:

```
string sortedWord = "abcd";
```

Maybe using char is a better option? How would I do this in C++?

Comment: What about `std::sort`?

Comment: Note that any sort of naive char value based sorting breaks with UTF-8 -- depending on your strings you might want to take the locale into consideration.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

There is [a sorting algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) in the standard library, in the header `<algorithm>`. It sorts inplace, so if you do the following, your original word will become sorted.

```
std::sort(word.begin(), word.end());
```

If you don't want to lose the original, make a copy first.

```
std::string sortedWord = word;
std::sort(sortedWord.begin(), sortedWord.end());
```

Comment: What if we want the string to sorted in increasing order?

Comment: @madhuspot `std::sort` sorts in alphabetically-increasing order by default. Supposing that's a minor typo and you want **de**creasing order, use the version of `std::sort` that takes a `Compare` as its third argument and supply `std::greater` instead of the default `std::less`. `std::string` uses the `char` type by default so e.g. `std::sort(sortedWord.begin(), sortedWord.end(), std::greater<char>());` — that would give a result of "dcba" in the original question rather than "abcd".

Comment: @madhuspot  or use std::reverse

Answer (score 17):

```
std::sort(str.begin(), str.end());
```

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)

Comment: This is the best way... IF the string is using a single byte encoding.  Otherwise you'll break apart characters into their component bytes.

Answer (score 3):

You have to include [`sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) function which is in [`algorithm`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/) header file which is a [standard template library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) in c++.

**Usage**: std::sort(str.begin(), str.end());

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>  // this header is required for std::sort to work
int main()
{
    std::string s = "dacb";
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

> `abcd`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sort()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function. sort() exists in [algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) header file

```
        #include<bits/stdc++.h>
        using namespace std;


        int main()
        {
            ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
            string str = "sharlock";

            sort(str.begin(), str.end());
            cout<<str<<endl;

            return 0;
        }
```

**Output:**

> achklors