# Sorting string in descending order.

Tags: c++, stl

Is there a string function in C++ (STL) to sort a string in descending order.
If not, how to sort a string in descending order in O(n) time.

Comment: the function is called `sort`

Comment: @Yathartha  Do you know an algorithm that sorts with O( n )?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107516/sorting-characters-of-a-c-string

duplicate

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, Counting sort is pretty close. It doesn't apply to strings (directly anyway), but it's an example.

Comment: Is it OK to take longer than O(n) if there is a suitable function in the standard library?  Or do you want O(n) from the library function?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be std::sort it, then std::reverse it.
sort is from algorithm.
reverse is from utility.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

int main(){

    std::string str = "Hello Beep 5412";

    std::cout << "normal string:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << str << std::endl;


    std::sort(str.begin(), str.end()); //sort it
    std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end()); //reverse it

    std::cout << "\nsorted, descending:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
normal string:
Hello Beep 5412

sorted, descending:
polleeeHB5421
```

Comment: Much simpler to use `std::sort` with `std::greater` than to reverse: `sort(begin(str), end(str), std::greater<char>());`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function in C++ to sort a string, and you can make it sort it descending order by telling it to compare with `std::greater` rather than `std::less`.

However, it won't sort in O(n) time (it will be O(n log n)).  You will need to use a bucket sort for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you need linear time, you can't use any of the general-purpose sort algorithms (they're all `O(n log n)` average case). So: no, there isn't a single suitable function in the standard library.

Something like a [Pigeonhole sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_sort) or other bucket sort would work: just track the frequency of each of the 256 possible characters, and re-write the string after.

Note that you still need an idea of the lexical ordering you want for your char values, but then you just rewrite your string by walking over your buckets in the correct (descending) order.